# Passing a member of a struct to a function by reference

Tags: c

How do I pass a struct MEMBER by reference? I do not want to pass the whole struct to the function.

I'm trying to make a function addString, that dynamicly allocates enough memory to store a string in a struct member.

It looks like that everything works fine until after the function addString finishes and I want to print the title member of the struct, there is still garbage in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct program
{
        int check;
        char* title;
        char* channel;
};

char* addString(char* destination, char* string);

int main(void)
{
        struct program* programs = (struct program*) malloc(sizeof(struct program)); //memory for the struct
        addString(&(programs->title), "test"); //passes the adress of the struct member to the function
        printf("%s", programs->title); //and when I print this there is still garbage in it and not the actual string "test"
        return 0;
}

char* addString(char* destination, char* string)
{
        *destination = (char*) malloc(strlen(string) + 1); //dynamic memory alloction for the length of the string
        strcpy(destination, string); //string copy to the pointer returned from the malloc here above
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: the main function is passing a pointer to a pointer to the addString function.  so addString needs to have a pointer to pointer parameter.

Comment: why is addString defined as returning a char * (which is being ignored in main()) and then actually returning a integer )which might be mistaken in main() (if main were paying attention to the returned value) as NULL?

Comment: If you enable all the warning on your compiler, you would have been informed of what is wrong with the program.  BTW: warnings need to be fixed, not ignored

Comment: When using the malloc (and family) functions in C, 1) do not cast the returned value from malloc 2) always check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Yes that was the mistake I made, my warning settings were fine but I just wasn't looking in the right place. And would it be better to change my function to void because I'm not actually returning anything? We have to cast when using malloc or other functions like these in school. "Because we will better understand what we are working with then".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your compiler should be throwing a warning at you over this code.

```
red.c:17:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'char *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    addString(&(programs->title), "test"); //passes the adress of the struct member to the function
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
red.c:12:23: note: passing argument to parameter 'destination' here
char* addString(char* destination, char* string);
                      ^
red.c:24:18: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    *destination = (char*) malloc(strlen(string) + 1); //dynamic memory alloction for the length of the string
                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   *
2 warnings generated.
```

Notably, `&(programs->title)` is of type `char **`, not `char *`.

#### An appropriate `addString()` function might look like:

```
void addString(char** destination, char* string) {
    *destination = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(*destination, string);
}
```

Comment: Aaah right, I've been trying to figure the problem out for over 2 hours. Thanks a lot! Just one more quick question, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I have my warning level on: EnableAllWarnings, but I do not get any warnings.

Comment: @CrazyEgoist: In general, newer compilers provide better warnings and error messages. I usually use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) on linux to get quality error messages (like the one I included in this answer).

Comment: @CrazyEgoist: Visual Studio 2013 will also warn about this: http://i.imgur.com/NK2hOnx.png

Comment: We use Visual Studio in school so I have to keep using it, but I'll try a newer compiler when I'm stuck again, thanks again!

Comment: Okay so I just checked again, when I test my code I mostly use the debugger and go trough my code line by line to see what happens in the memory and it looks like it sometimes doesn't show me any warnings at all. But I just saw that when I rebuild my solution it indeed shows me all the warnings, pretty nice. That will save me quite some time in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Following is a corrected version of your program. The main issue with addString method is that it should pass a pointer to pointer, rather than just a pointer

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct program //this is the struct that is in the file program.h
{
        int check;
        char* title;
        char* channel;
};

char* addString(char** destination, char* string); //Replace char* with char**

int main(void)
{
        struct program* programs = (struct program*) malloc(sizeof(struct program)); //memory for the struct
        addString(&(programs->title), "test123"); //passes the adress of the struct member to the function
        printf("%s", programs->title); //and when I print this there is still garbage in it and not the actual string "test"
        return 0;
}

char* addString(char** destination, char* string)
{
        *destination = (char*) malloc(strlen(string) + 1); //dynamic memory alloction for the length of the string
        strcpy(*destination, string); //string copy to the pointer returned from the malloc here above
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also thanks to you for helping me out! This was my first problem posted here and I didn't expect a response this fast.